# Use sed with special character

Tags: sed, character, cut

I try to use sed with special character:

```
sed -i -e "1i$jtempo" $file
```

$file is my file.
$jtempo is my variable with special character like: " or [ or (

But, when I run this script, I have this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown command: `"'
```

My file:

```
"desc_test":[
"id",
"name",
],
```

In my script bash:

```
jtempo=`cat myfile`
```

An idea ?
Thanks you !

Comment: I want to use sed to indicate the line.
1 is an example

Comment: Same, don't give an error for me. But I have an error and I do not know what is the problem

Comment: If I replace $jtempo with teststring, the command works. The $jtempo variable is:` jtempo=`cat myfile``

Comment: then add contents of `$jtempo` to question... but before that, check if `a='*([]'; sed "1i$a" "$file"`.. if it fails, keep adding characters from those in `$jtempo`  until you get a failure.. that way you'll find your own solution :)

Comment: do you get a valid response if you type `sed --version` ?If so please add that info to your Q. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat f1
"desc_test":[
"id",
"name",
],
$ cat ip.txt
1
2
3
```

I would suggest to avoid `i` command and use `r` command which will be robust regardless of file content

```
$ # to insert before first line
$ cat f1 ip.txt
"desc_test":[
"id",
"name",
],
1
2
3

$ # to insert any other line number, use line_num-1
$ # for example, to insert before 2nd line, use 1r
$ # r command will read entire contents from a file
$ sed '1r f1' ip.txt
1
"desc_test":[
"id",
"name",
],
2
3
```

Comment: Thanks ! But how to set the result directly in ip.txt file ?

Comment: use `-i` when using `sed`... use `cat f1 ip.txt > tmp && mv tmp ip.txt` for the first one..

Comment: Thanks you very much !